# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class when upgrade from java 11 to 17

Tags: java, java-11, java-17

our project uses [schema-repo-server][1].
The code for starting the schema-repo-server is below -

```
    package technorati.tut.fes;
    
    import org.schemarepo.server.RepositoryServer;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    public class Main2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("schema-repo.class", "com.technorati.camus.schemaregistry.ZooKeeperRepository");
            props.put("schema-repo.zookeeper.ensemble", "kafka01.cap.qa.opal.synacor.com:2181,kafka02.cap.qa.opal.synacor.com:2181,kafka03.cap.qa.opal.synacor.com:2181");
            RepositoryServer rs = new RepositoryServer(props);
            rs.start();
        }
    
    }
```

This code is working fine in java11.

I'm upgrading java version from java 11 to java 17. After the upgrade when I start the service I get below error.

Note: modules in the startup list are --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED

How can I fix this issue?

> 14:18:48 INFO  [org.schemarepo.server.RepositoryServer  ] Routing java.util.logging traffic through SLF4J
> Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
> at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
> at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
> at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
> at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
> at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
> at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:507)
> at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:159)
> at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:44)
> at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:122)
> at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
> at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
> at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
> at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
> at org.schemarepo.server.RepositoryServer.(RepositoryServer.java:97)
> at technorati.tut.fes.Main2.main(Main2.java:12)
> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
> at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
> at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
> at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
> at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
> at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:207)
> at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:53)
> at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:153)
> at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:89)
> at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:28)
> at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
> at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:32)
> at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
> at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
> ... 15 more
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @f0c8a99
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
> at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:56)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
> at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.(ReflectUtils.java:46)
> ... 29 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

This is working fine
[1]: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.schemarepo/schema-repo-server.

Note: I've added vm argument  `--illegal-access=permit --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` but still I'm facing this error on java-17

Answer (score 11):

Maybe try adding a vm parameter at lauch:

```
java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

The --illegal-access is set to become ineffective in Java 17 (all values are equivalent to deny) but it will still be possible to use the --add-opens command-line option, or the Add-Opens JAR-file manifest attribute, to open specific packages (cf. openjdk.java.net/jeps/403 )